# how to do a wshttp binding for a wcf webservice in xamarin.ios

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

i am working on accessing wcf webservice on my xamarin application.I generated proxy client from SVCutil.exe and included the .cs file into my project. As i try calling the method i get a error stating that MONOTUCH DOESNOT SUPPORT DYNAMIC CODE GENERATION. As a objective c developer i had added custom header for my wcf request and had done WSHttp binding before webservice call. Do i need to do the same with c# also.If so how should i do that.Please suggest .
thank you

Answer (score 0):

On iOS it is impossible to execute dynamically generated code. This is a limitation of iOS and not of MonoTouch or Xamarin.iOS. Additionally, this limitation is by design. The reasons being performance/batterylife/security.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#2.no-dynamic-code-generation

If you're not getting the same error in Objective-C as you're getting in Xamarin.iOS then you've done something different Xamarin.iOS then you've done in Objective-C. What this difference could be is impossible to tell without more information.

Answer (score 0):

WSHttpbinding it's not supported on Xamarin. Only BasicHttpBinding by now, it seems